# Error "#include <string> while compiling" when using Firebase Arduino library in Arduino Uno vs Ethernet shield

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I want to use FirebaseArduino library  (Realtime database) on my Arduino Uno vs Ethernet shield instead of using NodeMCU (Use wire instead of wireless).

 But when compiling source this error occurred:

```
Documents/Arduino/libraries/firebase-arduino-master/src/FirebaseArduino.h:20:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory 
#include <string>
```

**Question 1** 
How could I resolve this problem? 
**Question 2** 
Could I use this library on Arduino Uno vs Ethernet shield? (This is written for ESP8266)

Comment: Please include what you wrote in your code. This problem could be anything, currently I can only refer you to a similar issue. https://github.com/robertcedwards/httpFirebase

Comment: Following httpFirebase above, it needs one back-end to transfer data. Arduino + Ethernet + PHP Back-end -> POST data to firebase. But i want to   make serverless system. Arduino + ethernet => Firebase

Comment: But as you can see Arduino + Ethernet = no firebase.

Comment: But i don't know why ESP8266 can make this. Chip's architecture? So if i want to use wire instead of wireless, i must build a back-end to connect to firebase database.

Comment: Now this is an option how you could do it, but I would take it as a second option if the first one doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MCUs mounted on Arduinos don't have the horse power to handle https connections.
(https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-get-https-on-arduino 
 or https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=427354.0)
So I am going to build a small back-end to forward packet to Firebase Database. Like @King Reload mentioned:  github.com/robertcedwards/httpFirebase.